# How do I correctly find a value from part of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I was expecting the following code should print out only "2 is found", however it prints out both. The second one should not happen because 4 is not in the first 3 elements of the vector. Where did I make the mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
    if(find(a.begin(),a.begin()+3,2) != a.end()) cout << "2 found" << endl;
    if(find(a.begin(),a.begin()+3,4) != a.end()) cout << "4 found" << endl;
}
```

Result:

```
2 found
4 found
```

Comment: `find` returns the end value you passed it if the value is not found, which in this case is *not* `a.end()`.  The code should say `... != a.begin() + 3...`.

Comment: @n.m. I thought the right side of the interval is open so it stops at the third elements.

Comment: @TonyD Good call.  It could not return `a.end()` as it has no idea what that is.

Comment: @daydayup sorry you're right, I can't count.

Comment: @n.m. You are fine Sir. Indexing is always a trick.  Thank you very much for trying to help!

Comment: thank you everybody for the help. a.begin()+3 makes it work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns the end/"last" value you passed it if the value is not found, which in this case is *not* `a.end()`. The code should compare a la `... != a.begin() + 3...`.

Comment: @daydayup: sure, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Change `find(a.begin(),a.begin()+3,2) != a.end()` to `find(a.begin(),a.begin()+3,2) != a.begin()+3`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
    if(find(a.begin(),a.begin()+3,2) != a.begin()+3) cout << "2 found" << endl;
    if(find(a.begin(),a.begin()+3,4) != a.begin()+3) cout << "4 found" << endl;

}
```